# BST Path Traversal Confusion [C++]

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I've created a method called pathTo which returns a string of the path taken to find a string x. Here is the method:

```cpp
string BinarySearchTree::pathTo(BinaryNode* n, const string& x) const
{

    if (n == NULL)
    {
        return "";
    }

    if (n->value == x)
        return x;

    if (x.compare(n->value) < 1)
        return n->value + " " + pathTo(n->left, x);
    else
        return n->value +" " + pathTo(n->right, x);

    return x;

}
```

Although the above example works, the above example does not work when I change the last if else statement by checking the right side first instead of the left likeso:

```
if (x.compare(n->value) > 1)
    return n->value + " " + pathTo(n->right, x);
else
    return n->value +" " + pathTo(n->left, x);
```

This provides the wrong path which is what I am confused about. Why is it that the left side needs to be checked first?

Comment: What if `x.compare(n->value) == 1`?

Comment: You are assuming that the inverse of `... < 1` is `... > 1`. But the real inverse is `... >= 1`

Comment: BTW, you can write something like this:  `if (x < n->value)`

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - this never happens because our program never has the same word

Comment: Oh wait never mind I see, thanks!